# db2 can't connect from clients after restart

Tags: db2

I stopped my db using db2stop force. The started did a backup restarted and after that
i cannot connect to db from the a client anymore i get:
using the command

> db2 connect to "dbname" using "user"
>
> SQL30082N  Security processing failed
> with reason "42" ("ROOT CAPABILITY
> REQUIRED").  SQLSTATE=08001

password and username are correct. When im on the server connecting using command

> db2 connect to "dbname"

or

> db2 connect to "dbnmae" user "user"

or

> db2 connect to "dbname" user db2inst1

works just fine.
I m really confused. Any help is much appreciated
Thanks.

What i tried so far :

> db2 get dbm cfg | grep -i auth  GSS
> Plugin for Local Authorization
> (LOCAL_GSSPLUGIN) =   Server
> Connection Authentication
> (SRVCON_AUTH) = NOT_SPECIFIED
> Database manager authentication
> (AUTHENTICATION) = SERVER  Cataloging
> allowed without authority
> (CATALOG_NOAUTH) = NO  Trusted client
> authentication
> (TRUST_CLNTAUTH) = CLIENT  Bypass
> federated authentication
> (FED_NOAUTH) = NO

switched to client but did not using

> db2 update dbm cfg using
> authentication client

#### Update:

Despite the age of this question, it would be wonderful to have a solid answer to this question. Hi locojay, how did you manage?  :-)

I'm having the SQL30082N reason code 24 issue in my Windows PC, and today we experienced the same issue in an AIX server.

I googled for a couple hours and didn't find but one happy answer, related to having users with the same name both in the server and the client.
IMO it does not apply to me, as I'm running into a VBox that´s isolated from the domain (no network).

My case: I installed DB2 as user db2admin, no security. Then I granted DBADM to VIRTUALUSR01 and gave this user a password.

```
  db2 connect to TheBase
```

works fine. But

```
  db2 connect to TheBase user VIRTUALUSR01 using TheRightPassword
```

returns SQL30082N with reason code 24.

Comment: thnks to chris did solve it by using
db2 update dbm cfg using authentication client 
db2 update dbm cfg using trust_allclnts yes 
db2 update dbm cfg using trust_clntauth server db2stop
db2start

i still don't know what the hell happend. Google didn't help 
so hope this post will make googling for that prob better

Answer (score 3):

Using client authentication is generally a Bad Idea(TM).  That's because you now rely on machines that you may not control for authentication.  If I wanted to subvert your system, I could create a new user locally, say, db2inst1 or VIRTUALUSR01 or Administrator, with a password I know, and then, use that to wreak havoc on the database.  If, however, no one in your organisation has root/administrator authority over their own machines, client authentication can be made to work.  But all it takes is someone plugging in their own personal laptop, and your database could be at risk.

Instead, check the permissions of the files.  If you've installed as root, ~db2inst1/sqllib/security/db2c[hk]pw (assuming instance ID of db2inst1) should be setuid root.  If not, run db2iupdt against your instance (`./db2iupdt db2inst1`) which should fix the permissions.

If you've installed without root authority ("non-root install"), which I doubt, since you seem to have had this working, you would need to read the DB2 documentation on non-root installations and their limitations - I don't use non-root installs myself, so I'm not so familiar with them.  However, there should be a set-root script that you can use to enable setuid root which, of course, you have to run *as root*.

Comment: Thanks Tanktalus, for your blazing fast wise answer. 
In the computer I'm working on there are no security issues, at all. DB2 runs in a virtual machine buried into a highly protected PC. 
The same computer is the client and the server, i.e., the database connection is local. And tha data it contains has no valus, is a test case.

Comment: very helpful.  just don't forget to do it to all your instances.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved with the following way.

Problem occurs because of /etc/shadow file. If the user's password hash is created with SHA then DB2 cannot authenticate or authorize that user. You need MD5 for hashing that user's password.

If you are using Fedora or RedHat Linux, first change hashing method of passwords with:

```
# authconfig –-passalgo md5 –-update
```

Then drop and recreate the user:

```
# userdel userName
# useradd userName
# passwd userName
```

If you are using AIX or any other linux distros, authconfig won't work. So instead of passwd userName, issue this command:

```
# usermod --password `openssl passwd desiredPassword`
```

After that, your password hash belonging to userName will be generated with MD5.

Now grant user privilege to that user:

```
# su - db2inst1
(db2inst1)$ db2 connect to databaseName
(db2inst1)$ db2 GRANT DBADM with dataaccess with accessctrl on database to user userName
```

I hope it works for you too.

Thanks to Honza for his [solution](http://blog.stastnarodina.com/honza-en/spot/db2-sql30082n-security-processing-failed-with-reason-15/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Solutions to specific problem causes described previously in
     this message are:
     1. Run DB2IUPDT <InstName> to update the instance.

     2. Ensure that the username created is valid. Review the DB2
        General Naming Rules.

     3. Ensure that catalog information is correct.
```